# Making Material tabs scrollable

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm using Material tabs in my application (`mat-tab` s inside `mat-tab-group`)
When there are more tabs than can be displayed, two navigation buttons are shown to display the other tabs:

[image]

My requirement is to enable the user to scroll on the tab bar so that other tabs are shown.

I tried to do some css changes but couldn't solve it. It's highly appreciated if any solution or suggestion can be given.

Answer (score 9):

[Long text solution] My goal was to make mat-tabs scrollable by default, without controls, but with the ability to auto-scroll when clicking on partially visible mat-tab to move it to the visible center-ish viewport.

1) This behavior already partially realized in this example "from the box" - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tabs-scrollalble-initial-behavior. 
The problem is that you can't scroll backward normally - there some buggy behavior to push tabs to the left. So it does not work as I wanted.

2) The next variant was with scrolling event - take a `(wheel)="event"` on mat-tab-group - but its also not work with mobile. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tabs-scrollable-by-wheel-event Got it from this [awesome comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51545130/9026103).

3) My own scroll of mat-tabs with scrolling on mobile and autoscrolling clicked tab to center of screen' viewport when you click on the tab was not too simple but it works! :)

first, you need to disable "from the box" scrolling when tapping on tabs and pagination buttons:

mat-tabs-override.scss:

```
$black: #121212;
@mixin media-query-for-mobile {
  @media (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 1px) {
    @content;
  }
}
mat-tab-group {
  .mat-tab-header {
    .mat-tab-header-pagination {
      display: none !important; // <== disable pagination
    }
    .mat-tab-label-container {
      left: 0px; // if you need to use it on mobile - set left position to 0
      width: 100%;
      .mat-tab-list {
        overflow-x: auto !important; // <== set horisontal scroll bar imperatively
        // below rule prevents sliding of buttons' container - because it not sliding properly - to left it not slide as well
        transform: none !important;
        .mat-tab-labels {
          // some tweaks for tabs - up to you
          @include media-query-for-mobile {
            justify-content: unset !important; 
          }
          .mat-tab-label {
            // min-width: 20% !important;
            padding: 1.25% !important;
            margin: 0px !important;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: $black;
            font-weight: 600;
            min-width: 140px !important;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in this case you will see that all tabs are similar by width and scrollable on mobile.

Next, you need to make auto-scroll for tabs when you clicking on them and change their position to the center of the screen, based on the current viewport - let's do it!

We can create a directive, which will listen to the main container of `<mat-tabs-group>`, check width of scrollable container `.mat-tab-labels` and move the tab to be visible in viewport by auto-scrolling `.mat-tabs-labels` container to needed way:

directive in template:

```
<mat-tab-group scrollToCenter>
    <mat-tab label="tab 1"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="tab 2"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="tab 3"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="tab 4"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="tab 5"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="tab 6"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="tab 7"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="tab 8"></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

directive.ts:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

interface DOMRectI {
  bottom: number;
  height: number;
  left: number; // position start of element
  right: number; // position end of element
  top: number;
  width: number; // width of element
  x?: number;
  y?: number;
}

@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: '[scrollToCenter]',
})
export class MatTabScrollToCenterDirective implements OnDestroy {
  isMobile: boolean;
  subs = new Subscription();
  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef
  ) {
    this.subs.add(
      fromEvent(this.element.nativeElement, 'click').subscribe((clickedContainer: MouseEvent) => {
        const scrollContainer = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-tab-list');
        const currentScrolledContainerPosition: number = scrollContainer.scrollLeft;

        const newPositionScrollTo = this.calcScrollToCenterValue(clickedContainer, currentScrolledContainerPosition);
      })
    );
  }

/** calculate scroll position to center of viewport */
  calcScrollToCenterValue(clickedContainer, currentScrolledContainerPosition): number {
    const scrolledButton: DOMRectI = (clickedContainer.target as HTMLElement).getBoundingClientRect();
    const leftXOffset = (window.innerWidth - scrolledButton.width) / 2;
    const currentVisibleViewportLeft = scrolledButton.left;
    const neededLeftOffset = currentVisibleViewportLeft - leftXOffset;
    console.log(scrolledButton);
    const newValueToSCroll = currentScrolledContainerPosition + neededLeftOffset;
    return newValueToSCroll;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subs.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

And it works! :0 But not in ios and IE...
Why? Because ios and IE don't support Element.scroll()

Solution - `npm i element-scroll-polyfill` 
and set to polyfills.ts

```
/** enable polufill for element.scroll() on IE and ios */
import 'element-scroll-polyfill';
```

Great! but now scroll is not so smooth... IE and ios not support smooth-scroll-behavior.

Solution - `npm i smoothscroll-polyfill` 
and add to polyfills.ts

```
import smoothscroll from 'smoothscroll-polyfill';
// enable polyfill
smoothscroll.polyfill();
```

Finally it works everywhere. 
Hope it helps somebody to fix mat-tabs autoscrolling emptiness :)

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tabs-auto-scrollable-to-center-by-click)** Enjoy it :)

Answer (score 4):

Try my solution in this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bdswkd?embed=1&file=app/tab-group-basic-example.ts).

## First get a reference to the matTabGroup:

#### app.component.html

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup>
               ^^^^^^^^^
```

#### app.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('tabGroup')
tabGroup;
```

## Then listen to the mouse scroll wheel event and trigger a custom scroll function:

#### app.component.html

```
<mat-tab-group (wheel)="scrollTabs($event)" #tabGroup>
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### app.component.ts

```
scrollTabs(event) {
  const children = this.tabGroup._tabHeader._elementRef.nativeElement.children;

  // get the tabGroup pagination buttons
  const back = children[0];
  const forward = children[2];

  // depending on scroll direction click forward or back
  if (event.deltaY > 0) {
    forward.click();
  } else {
    back.click();
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: This solution is very brittle. The Angular Material tabs do not offer an API for doing this. The solution depends on internal references that might change without notice (e. g. this private variable `this.tabGroup._tabHeader`). Also, it does not yet stop the page from scrolling and only works with vertical scrolling. (Those two can be addressed though.)

Comment: Thanks. But this is a commercial level application. So l'm looking for a proper fix.

Comment: There cannot be a 'proper fix' without an official API from the material library. The solution is brittle in the sense that it might break with a libaray update (not only major releases) because it has to rely on internal (private) references. I'm afraid, the only proper solution would be a pull request to Angular Material

Answer (score 3):

Try this pure css solution 
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ww4ot)

Put this code in the same component where mat-tab is used

```css
::ng-deep .mat-tab-header {
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-tab-label-container { 
  overflow: visible !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-tab-header::-webkit-scrollbar { // TO Remove horizontal scrollbar in tabs
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: This solution doesnt enable scroll vertically without button click to display other tabs. This only hides the navigation @Bhavesh lalwani

Comment: This solutions ALMOST works perfectly. When enabling this the animation affect that happens when you click on element that is not completely visible on screen no longer happens. 

It seems this is related to the `overflow:visible` setting. If I remove this it works, but I can no longer scroll horizontally then. You can see the same thing in your example on StackBlitz if you scroll the menu so that a tab is only partially visible.

Comment: This worked great for Angular Material (12.1.0) scrolling/selection issues on narrower screens.

Answer (score 0):

adding drag event and drag start event on top of the mouse wheel event (posted above) to scroll a strd mat-tab under a mat-tab-group

```js
onDrag(event) {
  if (event.clientX > 0) {
    let deltaX = this.previousX - event.clientX;
    const children = this.tabGroup._tabHeader._elementRef.nativeElement.children;

    // get the tabGroup pagination buttons
    const back = children[0];
    const forward = children[2];
    console.log('dragging' + deltaX);
    // depending on scroll direction click forward or back
    if (deltaX > 3) {
      forward.click();
    } else if (deltaX < -3) {
      back.click();
    }
  }
  this.previousX = event.clientX;
  event.target.style.opacity = 1;
}
onDragStart(event) {
  this.previousX = event.clientX;
  event.target.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

```css
.noselect {
  user-select: none;
  /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<mat-card fxflex class="card component-right" *ngIf="editMode">
  <mat-card-content class="card-content">
    <mat-tab-group class="noselect" draggable="true" (drag)="onDrag($event)" (dragstart)="onDragStart($event)" (wheel)="scrollTabs($event)" #tabGroup>
      <mat-tab label="1st tab"> </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="2nd tab"> </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="3rd tab"> </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="4th tab"> </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="5th tab"> </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="6th tab"> </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

We can make mat tabs scrollable by adding below css code

```
 .mat-tab-labels
 {
 display : inline-flex !important;
 } 
 .mat-tab-label 
{
display:inline-table !important;
padding-top:10px !important;    
min-width:0px !important;
}
```

Comment: not working, how should it without defining an overflow

Answer (score 0):

Mat tabs are scroll-able by default.
Just check if you have not overridden that property any where like this CSS below ( **This CSS blocks the scroll behavior** )

```
.mat-tab-header-pagination-controls-enabled .mat-tab-header-pagination {
display: none !important;
}
.mat-ripple-element {
display: none !important;
}
```

Note:

> The tabs will be scroll-able when screen width is less than tabs-group
> width

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I going to hide buttons and made scroll only on touchable devices:

```
@media (hover: none) {
    ::ng-deep nav[mat-tab-nav-bar] > div {
        overflow-x: scroll !important;
        -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
        scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
    }
  
    ::ng-deep nav[mat-tab-nav-bar] > div::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none; /* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    }
  
    ::ng-deep nav[mat-tab-nav-bar] .mat-mdc-tab-list {
        transform: translateX(0) !important;
    }
  
    ::ng-deep nav[mat-tab-nav-bar] > button {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code to my css file worked as I expected.

```
    ::ng-deep .mat-mdc-tab-label-container {
    overflow-x: auto !important;
}
```