# Set horizontal scroll in angular material tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material

If we see the following tabs in the mobile's browser, there are two buttons [**pagination controls**] (the first one is on the right side and the other is on the left side)

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs class="example-stretched-tabs mat-elevation-z4">
    <mat-tab label="Item-1"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Item-2"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Item-3"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Item-4"> Content 4 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Item-5"> Content 5 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Item-6"> Content 6 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Item-7"> Content 7 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Item-8"> Content 8 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Item-9"> Content 9 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Item-10"> Content 10 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

[image]

I'm going to remove the two buttons and use scroll instead.

***Workaround :***

**(step-1)** Remove the two buttons with the following code :

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  document.getElementsByClassName('mat-tab-header-pagination-before')[0].remove();
  document.getElementsByClassName('mat-tab-header-pagination-after')[0].remove();
}
```

**(step-2)** put the following style in style.css:

```
.mat-tab-label-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
```

***Problem:***

The problem of the above method is when we select item-10 we can not scroll left

**[StackBlitz Here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6fgzsv)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solved these problems with scrolling by making my own auto-scroll effect on already scrollable mat-tabs - when you click on the partially visible tab - it will be autoscrolled to nearly center position, also left button will be scrolled to right, right partially visible button to left.

Please check this comment for more details: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62031767/9026103

Answer (score 13):

Instead of applying overflow style to .mat-tab-label-container, we can apply it to .mat-tab-header class.

```css
::ng-deep .mat-tab-header {
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-tab-label-container { 
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Also, If you want to remove the scrollbar which comes below the element where overflow-x: scroll is used, we can do the following:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-tab-header::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

**Solution**: The problem of the item-10 that cannot be scrolled left is solved by the above styles. I have forked @AbolfazlR repository and made the above changes. Below is the working example

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ww4ot)

Comment: based on your example I can not scroll right, see your stackblitz .. please try it

Comment: I tested the above stackblitz in ios(iphone 7) and android(one plus 5) both and I am able to scroll extreme right and extreme left irrespective of which tab is active. Would you please try it again or perhaps test on some other device

Comment: this helped put me in the right track. I am using mat-tab-nav-bar so the styles were applied to mat-tab-link-container

Comment: this is great! IMO - this should be the default behaviour not some sort ng-deep hack

Comment: The mouse wheel action is not working

Answer (score 6):

It seems it is a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/2236), and is still in open status.

A possible solution is using this scss rule(copied from the discussion of the issue) instead of the workaround you mentioned:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-header-pagination {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Your solution only remove pagination controls, but my main problem is another thing, Why I can not scroll left after selecting item-10

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry I misunderstood. Sadly, I have no clue: this might be a possible bug.

Comment: I'm so glad you misunderstood because you answered my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for not being able to scroll when the last tab is active is because Angular mat-tab control is using a transform to move the last tab into view and forcing it to the right side of container.

[image]

A possible solution is to squash the transform by adding this CSS class:

```
::ng-deep {

   // SOLUITON:
  .mat-tab-list {
    transform: inherit !important;
  }


  // FORCES SCROLLABILIY:
  .mat-tab-label-container {
    overflow-x: scroll !important;
  }

  // HIDES MAT-TAB's NATIVE PAGINATION:
  .mat-tab-header-pagination {
    display: none !important;
  }

}
```

**WARNING:**  the problem with this solution is it kills the transform effect and could be a poor user experience in so much as the user has to scroll for themselves.  Arguably, it's better then not being able to scroll left at all.