# Is there a way to properly use horizontal scroll for Angular Tabs?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

### The issue

I am trying to enable horizontal scroll using [Tabs from Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview)

Enabeling the horizontal scroll is easily done using overflow-x: auto.
However, when mixed with the transformation upon clicking a new tab or use of the arrows to the side it seems to move over the whole scrollable field. Leaving it impossible to use the scroll bar to go back to the beginning, it also adds white space on the side you scrolled to.

### What I tried

Since the overflow-x option is still more user friendly for our mobile users I then disabled the transformation when clicking a category and the arrows. When doing this, picking a category after scrolling sometimes doesn't work. You jump back to before scrolling, when trying again it does work.

```
::ng-deep
  .mat-tab-label-container{
    overflow-x: auto !important;
  }
::ng-deep  
  .mat-tab-header-pagination.mat-tab-header-pagination-after, .mat-tab-header-pagination.mat-tab-header-pagination-before {
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
::ng-deep  
.mat-tab-list {
  transform: unset !important;
}
```

Comment: Check the demo in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62031767/4550158) answer in particular - it seems to do exactly what you want.